# Javascript / Jquery Date Countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

Could anyone help me with a javascript countdown;

For Example: If it's 1:05pm on Sunday, it would say:
"Place your order within the next 1 day 2 hours 55 minutes and your order will ship Monday"
Another example: If it's 2:00pm on Saturday, it would say:
"Place your order within the next 2 hours and your order will ship today"

I need to be able to change the cut off point from 4pm if needed...

It must also ignore bank holiday (Ideally, it would have a section in the code where I could put all 'excluded' dates, e.g. 12/25/2009, 01/01/2010, etc. - This way I could keep it up to date).
The code must take into account that we only deliver Monday to Friday (Therefore on a Friday after 4pm, it would not say delivery tomorrow, but Monday).
Once the deadline hits (4pm), the countdown jumps back up to accommodate tomorrow's deadline, etc.
Amazon does a very similar thing, but I can't suss out what's going on

If you could help - it'd be appreciated. I've got the Jquery framework on my site if that helps...

Comment: Shouldn't this thing done on server side instead? I mean, can you actually trust the system clock on the client machine? What if the user is in another country so he or she is in a different timezone? Or just got off a plane and haven't adjusted the system timezone yet on the notebook?

Comment: It can be done with JS and UTC manipulation (I've been messing with this recently with mixed success), but for the sake of the OPs sanity I would say use some server side code.

Comment: I've voted server solution, but the date can be also provided from server, and to reduce server load it can be calculated on each visitor PC.

Comment: I can't use server side code as there's no server side code available :(

Comment: There's no issue using a start-time at render for a client-side object...just make sure you validate what is posted back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a example for your question, This may be helpful for you http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Comment: Yes here we can change the start date,time,seconds and end date,time,seconds also, just download the file and change the start and end date that's it.